# use undefined Dictionary<Type, Type> as an input to method

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to define a generic method for populating ComboBox controls on Windows Forms. I am usually using Dictionary to populate my combo boxes by binding them to the Data Source. Since I have a handful of those, I wanted to make a method that I can just call on any combination of a key, value pairs. Here's my attempt:

```
private void PopulateDropdown(ComboBox control, Dictionary<Type, Type> dict)
{
    if (dict.Count > 0)
    {
        control.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
        control.DisplayMember = "Key";
        control.ValueMember = "Value";
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to call it like so:

`PopulateDropdown(cbPrinters, this.inputData.Printers);` where  `this.inputData.Printers` is a Dictionary with key/value types as string, string but I also have other combinations like string, int or string,object.

I am getting an error that cannot convert string, string to Type, Type. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare your method with generic parameters:

```
private void PopulateDropdown<TKey,TValue>(ComboBox control, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
{
}
```

Comment: Ah! This seems to be working well. Thanks a lot for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a template to the function:

```
private void PopulateDropdown<Type>(ComboBox control, Dictionary<Type, Type> dict)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if both Key and Value types were the same for example string, string. but failed if they were string,int or string,object ?

Comment: Yes, this only works if both are the same type, but it's your case. If you want different types use René Vogt anwser

Comment: That's not my case, I have suggested in my question that I would have different combinations. It seems you have not read the question hence I down-voted your answer. Thank you

Comment: Then why did you write "Dictionary<Type, Type>" instead of "Dictionary<Type1, Type2>" in the title?